# Turn off error hiding on iis7

Tags: iis

I just installed IIS 7 on Vista, got PHP running, but I cant avoid the stupid default 500 error page if there is a problem with my php script, eg a compliation error etc.

How do I set up IIS (or maybe php) to show me the error thats causing the 500 problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control Panel -> System and maintenance -> Administrative tools -> Internet Information Services Manager. Either click the Computer name for all sites, or open it up and click a particular site, then open ‘Error Pages’, right click 500 and choose Remove. Repeat for any other error pages you don't want.

This command should also do it server-wide:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpErrors -existingResponse:PassThrough
```

If you're sure you want nothing to do with error pages on any of your sites, you can also completely remove the feature from Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> IIS -> WWW Services -> Common Http Features -> HTTP Errors.